# Error: Non-assignable model expression: undefined

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I'm trying to write tests for a directive, so I'm constructing it by hand with `$compile`. (Yes, I know that I can use e2e tests for this, but in this case I want to test some DOM independent logic so I'm using the unit test approach.)

I have a field that I'm binding to with `scope: {foo: '='}`. When I try to set it on the directive's scope, I get the following error:

```
Error: Non-assignable model expression: undefined (directive: foo)
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at $get.parentSet (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:4146:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:4160:23)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:7693:38)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:7894:24)
    at SNAKE_CASE_REGEXP (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:930:13)
    at Object.invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:2788:25)
    at bootstrap (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:928:12)
    at angularInit (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:904:5)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js:14397:5
```

Reproduced in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_nth/u4BTu/5/).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your directive you have:

```
scope: {
   bar: '='
}
```

This means it's going to look on the directive element (`<div foo></div>`) for an attribute name "bar" and do a two-way databinding within your directive and the object specified for the attribute. So, first you need to add a `bar` attribute, and then you need to have something set in your scope with the name of the value of the attribute. See http://jsfiddle.net/u4BTu/6/

Comment: Aside from commenting out 1 line at a time & refreshing, how can you tell which scope element its complaining about? Its not stated in the error messages for this error. Only the overall directive name. OPs example is obvious, but if it happens with a directive that has many bindings?

Comment: @JoshRibakoff One way is to throw a breakpoint in the Angular code and inspect the variables to see which parameter it's looking for in `nodeLinkFn` - specifically, the `definition` variable should contain helpful info.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of this error is neglecting to account for Angular's [normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization) of the attributes.  For instance, if you have the following directive:

```
<my-directive parameter-one="foo" parameter_two="bar"></my-directive>
```

With this scope declaration:

```
scope: {
  'parameter-one': '=',
  parameter_two: '=',
}
```

You'll get this error.  To correct, use the normalized versions for the scope declaration:

```
scope: {
  parameterOne: '=',
  parameterTwo: '=',
}
```